# Why is the right side of the cell not also highlighted?

Tags: browser, formatting

I have a link on my website that, when I click on it in Chrome v16.0.912.75 or Safari v5.0.6 (5533.22.3) becomes highlighted by a blue border.

The link html is as follows:

```
 <li><a href="http://example.com/" accesskey="1" tabindex="1">Home</a></li>
```

Clicking results in the following:

[image: Example]

Why is the right side of the cell not also highlighted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highlighted. But it seems you have another not-highlighted box on the right side. That's overlapping the border portion. Give some margin between them. For any help in CSS coding, head for Stackoverflow.